# Invoking UDF in Teradata

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, invoke, teradata

I have some troubles invoking SQL User Defined Functions in Teradata.
I've created the following function

```
*REPLACE FUNCTION "twm_source"."TD_FN_CALC" (
        "func" CHARACTER(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
        "a" INTEGER,
        "b" INTEGER)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    SPECIFIC "td_fn_calc"
    LANGUAGE SQL
    CONTAINS SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COLLATION INVOKER
    INLINE TYPE 1
    RETURN CASE
    WHEN func = 'A'
    THEN A + B
    WHEN func = 'S'
    THEN A - B
    WHEN func = 'M'
    THEN A * B
    ELSE A / B
END;*
```

But when I execute the following query against Teradata 14.0 Server

```
select "twm_source"."TD_FN_CALC"('M',3,8);
```

it gives error

> Failed [5589 : HY000] Function 'TD_FN_CALC' does not exist.

Could anyone please help me to find out what is wrong.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 5589 is returned when the parser couldn't match the literals to the function parameters:
A character literal ('M') is a VARCHAR while "func" is defined as CHAR.

There are two possible solutions:

- add an explicit typecast when you call the function

  `select "twm_source"."TD_FN_CALC"('M' (CHAR(1)),3,8);`
- change the definition from CHAR to VARCHAR. Works with both CHAR and VARCHAR input :-)

  ```
  "func" VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
  ```

Dieter

Answer (score 0):

Please change SPECIFIC "td_fn_calc" to SPECIFIC "twm_source"."td_fn_calc"

then call this function

> select "twm_source"."TD_FN_CALC"('M' (CHAR(1)),3,8);

If you just call this function with

> select "twm_source"."TD_FN_CALC"('M',3,8);

you will get error:

> -9881 function "*****" called with an invalid number or type of parameters.

Good luck!